# Conectar Con Un Dispositivo Bluetooth Vinculado

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth

Utilizo el siguiente codigo para obtener una lista de todos los dispositivos vinculados en el teléfono móvil:

```
  BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
            s.add(bt.getName());
        }


            for (int indice = 0; indice < s.size(); indice++) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Dispositivos: " + s.get(indice), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Tengo unos Audífonos Bluetooth **que ya están vinculados** y quiero que mi aplicación se conecte a esos audífonos de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Logre Solucionar mi propia pregunta pero no fue nada fácil...**

1- Se debe obtener la dirección mac del dispositivo a conectar en mi caso Un Modulo HC-06 bluetooth y se debe agregar donde comente `lugar para direccion mac`

2- Se crea una conexión con ese dispositivo

3- Se crea una comunicación para enviar y recibir datos

**Codigo Completo:
 MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.helencecilia.dispositivosbt;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


//Identificador de servicio
private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket;

//Si se apreta una vez el boton de conectar
boolean estado = false;

//Handler es un control para mensajes
Handler bluetoothIn;

//Estado del manejador
final int handlerState = 0;

//Esto es simplemente un String normal a diferencia que al agregar una sentancia en un bucle se agrega los espacios automaticamente
//for(hasta 20 veces)
//String cadena += " " + "Dato" ---> En un string normal se debe crear el espacio y luego agregar el dato
//Con esto se traduce a = DataStringIN.append(dato);
private StringBuilder DataStringIN = new StringBuilder();

//Llama a la sub- clase y llamara los metodos que se encuentran dentro de esta clase
ConexionThread MyConexionBT;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ////////////////Manejador de mensajes y llamara al metodo Run///////////////////////////////
    bluetoothIn = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dato Recibido Entero: " + readMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                DataStringIN.append(readMessage);

                int endOfLineIndex = DataStringIN.indexOf("#");

                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                    String dataInPrint = DataStringIN.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
               //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dato Recibido: " +dataInPrint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    DataStringIN.delete(0, DataStringIN.length());
                }
            }
        }

    };
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //BOTON ENVIAR
    Button btnEnviar = findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
    btnEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

            if(estado ) {
                String dato = editText.getText().toString();
                dato += "#";
                MyConexionBT.write(dato);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dato Enviado: " + dato, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Solo se puede enviar datos si el dispositivo esta vinculado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });


    //BOTON CONECTAR
    Button btnConectar = findViewById(R.id.btnConectar);
    btnConectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            //Direccion mac del dispositivo a conectar
            BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice("98:D3:32:21:02:F9");

            try
            {
                //Crea el socket sino esta conectado
                if(!estado)
                {
                    btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);

                    estado = btSocket.isConnected();
                }

                }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La creacción del Socket fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            // Establece la conexión con el socket Bluetooth.
            try
            {
                        //Realiza la conexion si no se a hecho
                        if(!estado)
                        {
                            btSocket.connect();
                            estado = true;
                            MyConexionBT = new ConexionThread(btSocket);
                            MyConexionBT.start();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Conexion Realizada Exitosamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ya esta vinculado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btSocket.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e2) {}
            }


        }
    });

}



//Crea el socket
private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException
{
    //crea un conexion de salida segura para el dispositivo
    //usando el servicio UUID
    return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
}


//Se debe crear una sub-clase para tambien heredar los metodos de CompaActivity y Thread juntos
//Ademas  en Run se debe ejecutar el subproceso(interrupcion)
private class ConexionThread extends Thread
{
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConexionThread(BluetoothSocket socket)
    {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try
        {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        int bytes;

        while (true) {
            // Se mantiene en modo escucha para determinar el ingreso de datos
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                // Envia los datos obtenidos hacia el evento via handler
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Enviar los datos
    public void write(String input)
    {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(input.getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //si no es posible enviar datos se cierra la conexión
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La Conexión fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }




}

}
```

**Diseño De La App: activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConectar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="63dp"
        android:text="Conectar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="190dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEnviar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
        android:text="Enviar" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</RelativeLayout>
```